# Does python operator not need condition statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw the code snippet that I think it is illegal, but not sure yet.

This is not exactly the same code, but I try to keep the original as much as I can.

```
def validate_check(string):
    try:
        len(string) > 0
        # do something
    except Error:
        # do something
```

Doesn't `len(string) > 0` have to be in condition statement? Or is it something python syntax?

Comment: What do you see when you run the code?

Comment: Depends on what you would like to do.. If you would like to do something if `string` is longer than 0 and only do it in that case, then yes.

Comment: @Austin No error. It works, that's why I am curios.

Comment: If it is not in a conditional statement, it will "Return" `True`/`False` but your return value will not be saved anywhere.

Comment: @jayko03, .. which means it is syntactically valid!

Comment: This looks like a convoluted and unreliable way to check that the parameter `string` is a `string` type (or has defined `__len__` method to be more precise). Try calling it with an integer for example.

Comment: Yeah, seems like someone forgot something. If it's not assigned nor checked in `if`, then that line doesn't do anything. How does the next line start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid syntax. But if you write:

```
len(string) > 0
print("hi")
```

then "hi" will be printed regardless of the length of the string. The only relevance this statement has is that it will throw an exception when either `string` has no length, or the result of `len(string)` is not comparable to 0.

What the author of the code is doing is avoiding the more complicated check `if isinstance(string, str) and string:` (or, I guess, `if isinstance(string, collections.abc.Sized) and len(string) > 0`).

Comment: what if I pass function to `len`? Then does it work like conditional statement?

Comment: If you pass a function to `len`, it will throw a `TypeError`, so in that case it will go to the `except` part.

Answer (score 4):

> Doesn't `len(string) > 0` have to be in condition statement?

No, but the example you've provided doesn't make a ton of sense.

Here's a different, similar construction that might help:

```
x = input()

try:
    10 / int(x)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't divide by zero")
except ValueError:
    print("Can't convert to int")
```

The result of `10 / int(x)` is calculated (to see whether it will raise an error), but the result of that calculation is thrown away.

The reason I say your example is a bit weird is because the comparison with zero will have no effect whatsoever.  So while the code will serve as a way of testing whether `len` can be called on `string`, that's about all it'll do.

Comment: I think you are right. I looked at code again, `len` has input function as a parameter. Isn't there any documentation that describes this?

Comment: @jayko03 do you mean it looks like `len(input())`?

Answer (score 1):

If string is `None`, the `len` function will raise an error.

Perhaps it's the reason why your function is named `validate_check`.